# can't receive clients ip address

Tags: c++, client-server, ip-address

I have a client server program in C++ console application. I run the server first then run the client. The server should display the ip address from the client that's connected but it says 0.0.0.0

I'm guessing its this line that's causing the problem

```
getsockname(ListeningSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&ServerAddr, (int *)sizeof(ServerAddr));
printf("Server: Receiving IP(s) from client: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ServerAddr.sin_addr));
```

in the client i set the ip address to 127.0.0.1

```
 ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: What does [`getsockname`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms738543(v=vs.85).aspx) return?

Comment: For best results: Test the client on a different machine to the server.

Comment: i am trying to run it on another computer but i have a problem with that. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297270/problems-with-running-exe-file-built-with-visual-studio-on-another-computer

Answer (score 1):

You get the clients address in the `sockaddr` provided to `accept`. If you later want a connected clients socket address you should use `getpeername` (*not* `getsockname`).

You also should pass a valid and initialized variable as the length to `getpeername` (or `getsockname`):

```
int size = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
getpeername(connectedsocket, (SOCKADDR*) &address, &size);
```

What you are doing now is attempting to get the local address of the server socket, but call it wrongly.

Comment: i am using getpeername in the program but i thought that was getting the servers ip addresss not the clients