# Running exe built with Code::Blocks on another computer

Tags: c++, windows, exe, codeblocks

I've compiled a "simple" C++ program on one computer running Windows 7 with Code::Blocks and would like to simply transfer it to another (Windows Vista) computer and run it with no problems. This other computer however has no libraries of its own and of course runs in to issues about missing DLLs the second the exe is loaded. e.g.

> The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing

But even statically linking with `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` doesn't make it end there because more DLLs are missing, the next being libwinpthread-1.dll. Transferring all the DLLs along with my program can work, but surely there must be a way to statically link all in to my program with Code::Blocks?

I've read [other SO threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297270/problems-with-running-exe-file-built-with-visual-studio-on-another-computer) which discuss the multithreading options for programs created in Visual Studio. Is there an equivalent option I'm not finding? And what if you're not even using an IDE at all?

Comment: Try `-static`, it will statically link as many things as possible.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks.