# What do I need to install to get x64 debug build of C++ hello world .exe running on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I created a C++ console application using the template in Visual Studio 2019.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

When I copy the .exe to  the server then

1. debug x64 build gives error (VCRUNTIME140_1d.dll missing)
2. release x64 build works

Server is: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, 64bit

Reading [this question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234416/can-visual-studio-2019-pack-the-dlls-it-requires-in-just-a-small-exe-file) says that debug DLLs are not allowed to be redistributed.

I need to debug on the server and I have paid for all licenses.

**What do I need to install to get debug build running on server?, e.g. full Visual Studio, Windows SDK, vc_redist.x64.exe?**

When I compare the installed programs on my development machine and on the server: Windows SDK is not installed on the server.

Comment: You need to copy vcruntime140_1d.dll to the machine, storing it in the same directory as the .exe.  Get it from, say, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.24.28127\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC142.DebugCRT.  Meant for remote debugging scenarios, do make it a practice of deploying only the release build.

Comment: @heboji3316, please check if the answer help you handle your issue and let us know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I need to install to get x64 debug build of C++ hello world
>   .exe running on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard?

**First**, thanks to **Hans** for all the help.

You can try these steps:

**Step**

**1)** when you migrate the `exe` file into the new server, you should put `VCRUNTIME140_1d.dll` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\xxx(VS version)\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.xx.xxx\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC142.DebugCRT` together with exe file.

**For example**, copy `VCRUNTIME140_1d.dll` into **Debug** folder which exists the `hello world.exe` file and then migrate the whole **Debug** folder into the new server.

**2)** or just install [vc_redist.x64.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) on your server.

More into you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297270/problems-with-running-exe-file-built-with-visual-studio-on-another-computer).